# Python matplotlib unequal dimensions for multiple plots on same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here is a snippet of code just to illustrate where the dimension of line1 and line2 is different from that of line3. How would you plot these several lines on the same plot. As it stands, matplotlib throws an exception.

```
def demo():
    x_line1, y_line1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    x_line2, y_line2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), 2*y_line1
    x_line3, y_line3 = np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([3,5,7])
    plot_list = []
    plot_list.append((x_line1, y_line1, "attr1"))
    plot_list.append((x_line2, y_line2, "attr2"))
    plot_list.append((x_line3, y_line3, "attr3"))

    #Make Plots
    title, x_label, y_label, legend_title = "Demo", "X-axis", "Y-axis", "Legend"
    plt.figure()
    for line_plt in plot_list:
        plt.plot(line_plt[0], line_plt[1], label=line_plt[2])
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1), loc="upper left", borderaxespad=0, title=legend_title)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The code as shown in the question is correct. If you get an exception (error), you need to include the full error traceback as well as the versions of your libraries and make the code a [mcve] (i.e. add the imports and clearly state how you run it). Using `hold=True` is deprecated and is unlikely to be a serious solution to any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all it takes is to add the "hold" as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122511/plot-arrays-of-different-lengths) even though it gives

> warnings.warn("axes.hold is deprecated, will be removed in 3.0")

So, the full solution to my future self and others is

```
def demo():
    x_line1, y_line1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    x_line2, y_line2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), 2*y_line1
    x_line3, y_line3 = np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([3,5,7])
    plot_list = []
    plot_list.append((x_line1, y_line1, "attr1"))
    plot_list.append((x_line2, y_line2, "attr2"))
    plot_list.append((x_line3, y_line3, "attr3"))

    title, x_label, y_label, legend_title = "Demo", "X", "Y", "Legend"
    plt.figure()  # add this to allow for different lengths
    plt.hold(True)
    for line_plt in plot_list:
        plt.plot(line_plt[0], line_plt[1], label=line_plt[2])
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1), loc="upper left", borderaxespad=0, title=legend_title)
    plt.show()
```