# How do I scale 2 datasets with different amounts of datapoint into one chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two datasets on the same plot, but am having trouble. The first dataset has 732 data points and 2 data-types (Timeseries and float) while the second dataset has 504 data points and 2 data-types. I am having massive trouble with scaling either of the datasets so that they look good together on the same graph. I continue getting the ValueError, `x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (732, 1) and (504, 1)`. Here is my code:

```
# ------ Benchmark Data
# ------ S&P 500 Adjusted-Closing Info
IXIC = wb.DataReader(
    '^IXIC', data_source = 'yahoo', start = '08-05-2018', end = '08-05-2020')['Adj Close'].to_frame()


# ------ Client's Data
file_name = '/Users/X/Desktop/CharlesSchwab.Client.PV.csv'
Client_Data = pd.read_csv(file_name)

# ------ Date Info
Client_Data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Client_Data['Date'])
Dates = pd.date_range(min(Client_Data["Date"]), max(Client_Data["Date"]))
df_Dates = pd.DataFrame(Dates).iloc[::-1]
df_Dates.columns = ['Dates']

# ------ Personal Value Info
PV = pd.DataFrame(Client_Data["Personal Value"].str.replace('$','').str.replace(',','').astype(float))

# ------ Plot data
t = df_Dates
data1 = PV
data2 = IXIC

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, did you try using `plt.hold()` And in that instead of having one variable `t`, you need to set the `x-value` equal to the length of the given dataset. Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122511/plot-arrays-of-different-lengths/22122632) might help

Comment: You should include some data in your question. We don't have access to your csv.  Please read [mre].

Comment: @wwii 
 PV: file:///var/folders/8x/vs15bfqs0314mb2j4dlyk9sh0000gn/T/com.apple.mail/com.apple.mail.drag/CharlesSchwab.Dad.PV.csv

Comment: @wwii the IXIC is just scrapped data from yahoo finance!

Comment: Thank you, @AnuragReddy I'll give it a shot and let you know what happens :)